# Can I approximate impedance Z% to X% neglecting resistance in > 25MVA transformers?

Tags: transformer, impedance

I extracted this table from *Network Protection & Automation Guide - Alstom* which is based on IEC 60076 (although X/R ratios are not part of IEC 60076).

[image]

And I saw that X/R ratios increase as rated power. Also, as I'm looking for a transformer bigger than 100MVA, can I assume that Z% is equal to X% in order to calculate its leakage inductance?

Answer (score 1):

If you assume Z = X and R =0, what would the actual value of Z if X/R = 5? Say X = 2%. For X/R = 5, R would be 0.4%. The aortal value of Z is the square root of the sum of the squares of X and Z or Z = 2.04%. So you have a small error. In other words, if X/R is 5 or larger, R is negligable.

Answer (score 1):

From AS 3851:1991, "The calculation of short-circuit currents in three-phase a.c. systems,

[image]

So X/R may be assumed as X/R = 10 for transformers less than 10 MVA, or X/R = (30 × log10 (MVA)) - 20 for transformers larger than 10 MVA.

This is a snippet of information that's in the Australian Standard AS 3851, that isn't present in the "parent" IEC standards. Or, as the introduction of AS 3851 puts it:

[image]